# Можно ли сделать чтобы картинки выпали за контейнер

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Если не кидать в контейнер то вообще черти что выходит,как правильно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
         <div class="team">МЫ КОМАНДА</div>
         <img class="team-img" src="img/team.png" alt="" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
         <div class="our">НАШИ ПРЕИМУЩЕСТВА</div>
      </div>
      <img class="our-img" src="img/our.png" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хотите лучшего управления над стилями - используйте CSS а не классы бутстрапа

Comment: Честно говоря я не совсем понимаю суть вашего вопроса. Что значит картинки "выпали" из контейнера? И как по мне, у вас не вполне правильное использование тега `<div class="team">МЫ КОМАНДА</div>` Используйте для заголовков теги h1,h2,h3 и так далее.

Comment: А что есть не картинку за контейнер расположить, а тексту в контейнере задать дополнительные опции?

Answer (score 0):

Оберните картинку в див, который будет заползать на отступы бутстрапа и тянуть изображение на всю свою ширину:

```css
.img-wrap{
  position: relative;
  margin:0 -15px;
}
.img-wrap img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
     <div class="team">МЫ КОМАНДА</div>
     <div class="img-wrap"><img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/></div>
     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
     <div class="our">НАШИ ПРЕИМУЩЕСТВА</div>
  <div class="img-wrap"><img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/></div>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```